# the reverse of PV of a series of cashflows

Tags: finance

I have calculated the PV of a set of cashflows over a period of 10 years.

Here is the equation:
YEAR/CASHFLOW

1. 50,000
2. 51,500
3. 53,045
4. 54,636
5. 56,275
6. 57,964
7. 59,703
8. 61,494
9. 63,339
10. 65,239

PV of the cashflows = $415,940 at a discount rate of 6%

Here's where I get confused:

Now that I know the PV, why then, if I take this amount, $415,940 and I invest it at a rate of 6% pa and each year a negative cashflow, corresponding to the table above, is paid out of the account, why does the figure at the end of year 10, not equal zero?  Is that not a reverse of the PV equation?

Comment: It _does_ equal zero. Check your calculation.

Comment: Also note: You lost some accuracy due to rounding. A more accurate present value is $415940.7235$

Comment: Do you think you could show me the calculation you are doing please?  I get a large negative number by year 10 when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Maple, I get the following . . .

[image]

Comment: I get the same results in Excel. If you round NPV to 415,940 and round all year end values to 2dp then there is a small negative balance (-1.30) at the end of year 10.

Comment: Thank you so much, yep that worked.  Im not sure what I was doing wrong, perhaps just staring at the equation for too long!!